# Checking the contents of python dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

This is probably a simple question, but how see how the contents of this standard data loader looks like:

```
from torchtext import datasets
import random

train_data, test_data = datasets.IMDB.splits(TEXT, LABEL)
train_data, valid_data = train_data.split(random_state = random.seed(SEED))
```

I can't use .head() and:

```
print(test_data)
```

just gives me:

```
<torchtext.datasets.imdb.IMDB object at 0x7f0b42e8c240>
```

I'm probably just missing .values or [0] or something similar...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Datasets are iterables, you can get the first element with `next(iter(test_data))`.

Comment: next(iter(test_data)).text did it. Thanks!